# Finding N observations with similar characteristics in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have three datasets with different number of observations and 5 features: X1=rand(100,5), X2=rand(75,5) and X3 = rand (90,5). Now, I should select 40 observations sharing approximately similar characteristics between X1, X2, and X3. That is 40 from each i.e 40 from X1, 40 from X2 and 40 from X3.

Can someone please help me with this? I tried indexPairs = matchFeatures(X1,X2) but it only gives me a limited set of observations (20) and I can't use this simultaneously for all three observations.

Comment: What does “similar characteristics” mean? All your samples are similar because they are drawn from the same distribution. Please be more specific!

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I just gave an example here but X1, X2, X3 are drawn from different distributions. By similar characteristics, i mean the five features are nearly similar between X1, X2, X3 (or the euclidean distance between them is minimum)

Comment: Ah, minimum Euclidean distance. Now you’re being sufficiently specific. Please [edit] that into your question. Would it be OK to pick one sample randomly and then find the next 39 samples that are nearest to it?

Comment: Basically the idea is to pick 40 samples from each dataset (40 from X1, 40 from X2, 40 from X3) that share nearly similar characteristics.